# How do you filter empty strings from an array within an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mongodb, filter

**Input**:

```
const stringA = "Title 1";
const arrayA = ['1', '2', '', '4']
const additionalValues = [
    {
        title: "Title 2", 
        descriptions: ['1', '', '3']
    }, 
    {
        title: "Title 3", 
        descriptions: ['1', '2', '']
    }
]
```

**API**:

```
let dataFields = []
if (stringA) {
    const cleanArr = arrayA.filter(e => {
        return e !=null && e !='';
    });
    dataFields.combinedArray = [
        {
            title: comp,
            descriptions: arrayA ? cleanArr : [],
        },
        ...additionalValues,
    ];
} else {
    dataFields.combinedArray = [];
}

data= new Data(dataFields);
await data.save();
res.status(200).send("Success");
```

**Output:**

**Current Result of `data.combinedArray`:**

```
[
    {
        title: "Title 1", 
        descriptions: ['1', 2, '4']}, 
    {
        title: "Title 2", 
        descriptions: ['1', '', '3']
    }, 
    {
        title: "Title 3", 
        descriptions: ['1', '2', '']
    }
]
```

**Desired Result of `data.combinedArray`:**

```
[
    {
        title: "Title 1", 
        descriptions: ['1', 2, '4']}, 
    {
        title: "Title 2", 
        descriptions: ['1', '3']
    }, 
    {
        title: "Title 3", 
        descriptions: ['1', '2']
    }
]
```

I'm currently trying to capture a title as a string (`stringA` ) and an array of descriptions (`arrayA`) then pair them together as an object inside of an array (`combinedArray`). If there are additional objects with titles and/or descriptions (`additionalValues`) I'm adding those to that same array of objects.

What I'm looking to do is filter out any null or empty strings before putting them together in the combined array of objects. I've successfully filtered the `arrayA` array and have been able to combine everything together the way I intended.

**The issue I'm having is** I need to filter through the arrays of descriptions inside the `additionalValues` to remove the empty strings/values as well. I've tried mapping through the `additionalValues` array then filtering the descriptions and trying to return that array of filtered objects before putting them into the combined array of objects ('combinedArray'), but have yet to figure it out.

Please Help! Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide an example input? The current example you posted is not a valid array.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> [mcve]

Comment: Updated the structure better to answer your questions.

Comment: To make this easier please provide some lines that set the data to a variable. e.g. var data = {"oh":'ook', great: ['etc']};  The data you've pasted can't be used to create a valid object.

Comment: Converted the frontend logic to variables for ya.

Comment: nvm... figured it out on my own. Posted the answer encase anyone needs it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const stringA = "Title 1";
const arrayA = ['1', '2', '', '4']
const additionalValues = [
    {
        title: "Title 2", 
        descriptions: ['1', '', '3']
    }, 
    {
        title: "Title 3", 
        descriptions: ['1', '2', '']
    }
]
```

```
if (stringA) {
    const cleanArr = arrayA.filter(e => {
        return e !=null && e !='';
    });
    let cleanAdd = additionalValues.map((c, i) => {
        const cleanAddArr = c.descriptions.filter((e) => {
            return e != null && e != "";
        });
        let cleanAddArrObject = {
            title: c.title,
            descriptions: cleanAddArr,
        };
        return cleanAddArrObject;
    });
    dataFields.combinedArray = [
        {
            title: comp,
            descriptions: arrayA ? cleanArr : [],
        },
        ...cleanAdd,
    ];
} else {
    dataFields.combinedArray = [];
}
```

```
[
    {
        title: "Title 1", 
        descriptions: ['1', 2, '4']}, 
    {
        title: "Title 2", 
        descriptions: ['1', '3']
    }, 
    {
        title: "Title 3", 
        descriptions: ['1', '2']
    }
]
```